# Minimize windows do not appear on my taskbar

Tags: windows

When I minimize my windows like Google chrome, mozilla fire fox, notepad, . they do not appear on my taskbar.

Instead they appear on my desktop.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: The odds of someone being able to help would be much better if you can provide basic information about your system.  What operating system?  That is probably needed even to know what to ask you next.

Comment: Have you tried logging out and back in? Restarting the PC?

Answer (score 0):

Try these options to isolate and fix the issue.

1. Check the open applications status with another user profile. If the applications seems to fine and showing at the task bar then it may the current user profile issue and may be corrupted
2. Open Task Manager and kill 'explorer.exe'. Then click on "New Task" icon and browse it to the 'explorer.exe' (\Windows) and open it.
3. Or, perform "sfc /scannow" command in the command prompt and restart the machine once the scan is over.

Hope this helps.